# Adding bin folder to server gives GenericErrorPage

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to add AjaxToolKit to the bin folder on my server. I have created a bin folder as it did not existed previously and copied `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` and `AjaxControlToolkit.pdd`to the bin folder. As soon as I do that I get this error. `GenericErrorPage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/Default.aspx`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using custom errors ? if so, disable it in order to get the actual error, then we will be able to help you. Also, make sure you are using the appropriate version of the AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: How do I decide the appropriate version of the Toolkit ?

Comment: i would recommand the latest

Comment: Well, if you manually copy the referenced assemblies into your bin folder, make sure the version of the assembly matches the version of the assembly referenced in your project / defined in your web.config file. If you do not want to do that, just right click the reference in your project, properties et set local copy to True.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to put your ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll to your bin folder, visual studio does it automaticaly.
Just add your dll as a reference, even if it's in a totaly different folder from the one on your server, and visual studio will do the rest, add all the folders linked to the dll, including language packs etc.. into the bin folder.

Maybe the only thing you have to do is to add your ajaxcontroltoolkit controls to your 'toolbox', by adding a new tag, then selecting the elements you wish to have in it.

Comment: I am not publishing my website using visual studio.

Comment: well normaly, you should have (in your project/bin) the necessary dll then. if you don't publish via visual studio, you still should have that ajaxcontroltoolkit dll already inside the bin folder of your project

Comment: I have it locally because I just added the Toolkit to have HTMLEditorExtender on the textarea. Now I want to have the same webpage control on the server.

Comment: Are you just copy-pasting the source files from your dev environment into your server environment ? Because this cannot work, you have to publish your website, either directly on your server, either locally and THEN only copy paste your published content.

Comment: you will have to compile, and replace your bin folder on your server, by the one in your project, you can't just add files that are not in the project/bin folder and paste them while not compiling